# Convert some bytes from a unsigned char to int

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, char, int

I want to convert some bytes to an int.
This is my code so far:

```
unsigned char *bytePtr = (unsigned char *)[aNSDataFrame];
```

I want to take 4 bytes from this unsigned char: 
`myFrame[10]`, `myFrame[11]`, `myFrame[12]` and `myFrame[13]` and convert them to an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int bytesToInt(unsigned char* b, unsigned length)
{

    int val = 0;

    int j = 0;

    for (int i = length-1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        val += (b[i] & 0xFF) << (8*j);
        ++j;
    }
    return val;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but it begin to myFrame[0] , i want it to begon at myFrame[10]

Comment: I would assume this is once again not original content? It looks a lot like http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/235158-converting-bytes-to-integer/ for example. If so, please always clearly indicate where you got the content from. Don't claim it is your own.

Answer (score 1):

you can do,

```
int a;
a=myframe[10];
a=a<<8;
a=a|myframe[11];
a=a<<8;
a=a|myframe[12];
a=a<<8;
a=a|myframe[13];
```

this will create integer containing those bytes

Comment: On little-endian platforms `myframe[13]` should be the most significant byte.

Answer (score 1):

```
int val = *(const int*)&myFrame[10];
```